# whats is the song that plays in naruto episode 479 when sasuke talks about naruto when the infinite tsukuyomi?

Tags: naruto, music, theme-song

I can't seem to find that song but it's when the tailed beasts are released and sasuke talks about naruto in episode 479

Answer (score 1):

I had also been searching for this for a long time and finally found it. It's a little fast-forwarded version of "Departure to the Front Lines". Here is a Youtube link for it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ISfifczkgM